# Migrate apt-cacher-ng cache

Tags: 18.04, apt-cacher-ng

I have a Debian 10 server with apt-cacher-ng and would like to migrate the cache to an Ubuntu 18.04 server. Is it enough to just copy the `/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/` directory over? Or is there some import functionality needed?

Comment: Debian is off-topic for ASKuBUNTU.

Comment: Migration destination is Ubuntu 18.04, so if any import has to be done, it would have to be done on the Ubuntu-side.

Comment: Also, where is one supposed to post migration-related questions? It's OT here because it involves Debian. But, following that logic, it would be OT in a Debian forum because it involves Ubuntu. Just curious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, social distancing frees up some time. So here's what I did just now:

Stop all apt-cacher-ng instances on source & destination servers: `systemctl stop apt-cacher-ng`

Create an archive of the cache on the source: `tar cvzpf archive.tgz /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng`

Use your prefered tool to copy the archive to the destination: `scp archive.tgz user@destination`

Extract archive on the destination: `tar xvzpf archive.tgz /var/cache/`

Start apt-cacher-ng instance on destination server: `systemctl start apt-cacher-ng`

Check if apt-cacher-ng is running on the destination by visiting http://new.server.tld:3142/acng-report.html in a web browser

Check if everything works by running `apt-get update` / `upgrade` on some apt-cacher-ng clients

NOTES:

On the client-side I use a DNS alias "apt-cacher" to point to the real hostname. This may still be cached by the clients, so I had to do `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` on some apt-cacher clients and `ipconfig /flushdns` on the windows web client. DNS TTLs are typically not longer then a day, so any problems should resolve themselves eventually. On the other hand, if you don't do it like that, you'll have to modify the apt configuration on all clients to point to the new server: `Acquire::http { Proxy "http://new.server.tld:3142"; }`

This process will (to my surprise) preserve the "Transfer statistics" on the report-page but NOT the "Log analysis". If you want that, you should probable copy `/var/log/apt-cacher-ng/` as well

I still have an issue that the report webpage is rendered incompletely when I first load it. But I'm not sure if it's related to the migration, Ubuntu or something else. Reload helps, so for now I'll leave it at that